# How to calculate the last week of every month?

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I've been having a look around but I can't seem to find anything that answers this question. I want to calculate the date for the last week of every month. For example, the date for the last week of April 2021 is 26-04-2021. I want a date, not a week number.

I use Google Big Query, I do have a calendar table I could use to extract year and month.

Thanks,
Emily

Comment: Do you have a list of the dates of each month? I am not familiar with Google Big Query but the algorithm you are looking for is probably something in the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352313/how-to-calculate-last-week-of-month-by-weekno-and-year-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Try [date_trunc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc):

```
SELECT date_trunc(last_day(month1st, month), week(monday))
from unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-01-01', '2021-12-01', interval 1 month)) AS month1st;
```

[image]